# Dynamic Workflow with asp.net mvc and WF 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, workflow

I have an asp.net mvc3 application and now I want to hook into it with Workflow 4.0. I want users to be able to define workflows through the user interface and have a way to mingle them with business processes. Can WF 4.0 help me achieve my requirements?

If this is possible, please refer some helping material for WF 4.0 with mvc. If it's not possible with WF 4.0 what options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

WF4 is a huge learning curve, and is quite heavyweight in its processes, I have had alot of difficulty integrating WF4 within ASP.NET MVC, and even more difficulty debugging the thing.

Now, while I agree that learning new things is good, I eventually settled upon the use of a StateMachine, I have developed and am using my own, but I have found [StateLess](http://code.google.com/p/stateless/) since, which also works very well.

I hope this helps,

Matt